# How do I browse JDT source code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

My current attempt to browse the JDT source code in eclipse:

- installing Eclipse Helios RCP version.
- importing all plugins from installation as binary files into my workspace

It does not work.

Answer (score 10):

Install the "Eclipse SDK" feature from the Eclipse Project Updates update site:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can follow Vogella's "[**Eclipse Source Code - Tutorial**](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html)", especially the section "**Import Plugins**"

> how you can import Eclipse plugins from your Eclipse installation to review the code.
>   The Eclipse distribution contains the source code for the core Eclipse projects, e.g. JDT.
>   For other Eclipse projects you usually find a "SDK" bundle on the project update side which contains the source code.
>
> To avoid "pollution" of your existing workspace, switch to a new workspace and select `File ->  Import`. Select "`Plug-ins and Fragments`".

[image]

> Make the following settings.
>   Select "**Binary projects**". In Binary project you can read the source code but you cannot change it. They will also not be compiled therefore this setting will save memory and performance.

[image]

> Add all plugins you would like to import and press "Finish".

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I did in the second step.