# Debugging into class method in eclipse/jdt jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar

I need to debug into the elcipse jar file, as I have null return value all the times.

[image]

I need to attach source file for the jar that I need to debug. As eclipse is open source, I guess I can find the source, but how can I get the source code for the jar file that I'm debugging into?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could debug into the core files by following this pages:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html
- [How do I browse JDT source code in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745495/how-do-i-browse-jdt-source-code-in-eclipse?rq=1)