# How to get the source jar file for eclipse jdk plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-jdt

I'm using Eclipse Juno for RCP and RAP Developers.

[image]

Following [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html), I could import plug-ins and fragments to trace into eclipse jdt source code. However, I couldn't get the source for the method in `org.eclipse.jdt.code`.

[image]

And I found that there is no jar file with source jar file for `org.eclipse.jdt.core`.

[image]

compared to some jar files that has source jar file.

[image]

- How can I get the source jar file for org.eclipse.jdt.core? Can I simply download the file? Do I need to build the jar from scratch?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745495/how-do-i-browse-jdt-source-code-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prunge's answer helped me to find out the solution to my issue.

I first used the method in [Vogella's Eclipse Source Code - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) to import org.eclipse.jdt.core into the project, and then [Eli Acherkan's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7074062/260127) to install Eclipse SDK. Only after I uninstall the eclipse source code out of my project, I can trace into the method/class in eclipse source base.